# Why am I getting this error ? error CS0103: The name 'EnhancedStackTrace' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, build, compiler-errors, fivem

I am a beginner in C# and cpp, and When I'm trying to build the FiveM launcher from the the [FiveM launcher OpenSource code](https://github.com/citizenfx/fivem) FiveM launcher OpenSource code, I'm getting this error after doing fxd build.

```
"C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\dev\fivem\launcher\fivem\code\build\five\CitizenMP.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\dev\fivem\launcher\fivem\code\build\five\CitiMono.csproj.metaproj" (default target) (76) ->
"C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\dev\fivem\launcher\fivem\code\build\five\CitiMono.csproj" (default target) (105) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\dev\fivem\launcher\fivem\code\client\clrcore\InternalManager.cs(620,13): error CS0103: The name 'EnhancedStackTrace' does not exist in the current context [C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\dev\fivem\launcher\fivem\code\build\five\CitiMono.csproj]
```

And this is part of the code of the *InternalManager.cs* line 575 to line 634 where I get the error for the ***EnhancedStackTrace***.

```cs
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        private void PrintError(string where, Exception what)
        {
            ScriptHost.SubmitBoundaryEnd(null, 0);

            var stackTrace = new StackTrace(what, true);

#if IS_FXSERVER
            var stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
#else
            IEnumerable<StackFrame> stackFrames;

            // HACK: workaround to iterate inner traces ourselves.
            // TODO: remove this once we've updated libraries
            var fieldCapturedTraces = typeof(StackTrace).GetField("captured_traces", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (fieldCapturedTraces != null)
            {
                var captured_traces = (StackTrace[])fieldCapturedTraces.GetValue(stackTrace);

                // client's mscorlib is missing this piece of code, copied from https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/ef848cfa83ea16b8afbd5b933968b1838df19505/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/StackTrace.cs#L181
                var accum = new List<StackFrame>();
                foreach (var t in captured_traces ?? Array.Empty<StackTrace>())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < t.FrameCount; i++)
                        accum.Add(t.GetFrame(i));
                }

                accum.AddRange(stackTrace.GetFrames());

                stackFrames = accum;
            }
            else
                stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
#endif

            var frames = stackFrames
                .Select(a => new
                {
                    Frame = a,
                    Method = a.GetMethod(),
                    Type = a.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType
                })
                .Where(a => a.Method != null && (!a.Type.Assembly.GetName().Name.Contains("mscorlib") && !a.Type.Assembly.GetName().Name.Contains("CitizenFX.Core") && !a.Type.Assembly.GetName().Name.StartsWith("System")))
                .Select(a => new
                {
                    name = EnhancedStackTrace.GetMethodDisplayString(a.Method).ToString(),
                    sourcefile = a.Frame.GetFileName() ?? "",
                    line = a.Frame.GetFileLineNumber(),
                    file = $"@{m_resourceName}/{a.Type?.Assembly.GetName().Name ?? "UNK"}.dll"
                });

            var serializedFrames = MsgPackSerializer.Serialize(frames);
            var formattedStackTrace = FormatStackTrace(serializedFrames);

            if (formattedStackTrace != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"^1SCRIPT ERROR in {where}: {what.GetType().FullName}: {what.Message}^7");
                Debug.WriteLine("{0}", formattedStackTrace);
            }
        }
```

And the **EnhancedStackTrace** is also being used in the file *MonoComponentHost.cpp* and this part of the code where it is being used it's from line 267 to line 327.

```cpp
static void InitMono()
{
    // initializes the mono runtime
    fx::mono::MonoComponentHostShared::Initialize();

    mono_thread_attach(mono_get_root_domain());
    g_rootDomain = mono_get_root_domain();

    mono_add_internal_call("CitizenFX.Core.GameInterface::PrintLog", reinterpret_cast<void*>(GI_PrintLogCall));
    mono_add_internal_call("CitizenFX.Core.GameInterface::fwFree", reinterpret_cast<void*>(fwFree));

#ifndef IS_FXSERVER
    mono_add_internal_call("CitizenFX.Core.GameInterface::TickInDomain", reinterpret_cast<void*>(GI_TickInDomain));
#endif

    mono_add_internal_call("CitizenFX.Core.GameInterface::GetMemoryUsage", reinterpret_cast<void*>(GI_GetMemoryUsage));
    mono_add_internal_call("CitizenFX.Core.GameInterface::WalkStackBoundary", reinterpret_cast<void*>(GI_WalkStackBoundary));
    mono_add_internal_call("CitizenFX.Core.GameInterface::SnapshotStackBoundary", reinterpret_cast<void*>(GI_SnapshotStackBoundary));

    std::string platformPath = MakeRelativeNarrowPath("citizen/clr2/lib/mono/4.5/CitizenFX.Core.dll");

    auto scriptManagerAssembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(g_rootDomain, platformPath.c_str());
    if (!scriptManagerAssembly)
    {
        FatalError("Could not load CitizenFX.Core.dll.\n");
    }

    auto scriptManagerImage = mono_assembly_get_image(scriptManagerAssembly);

    bool methodSearchSuccess = true;
    MonoMethodDesc* description;

#define method_search(name, method) description = mono_method_desc_new(name, 1); \
            method = mono_method_desc_search_in_image(description, scriptManagerImage); \
            mono_method_desc_free(description); \
            methodSearchSuccess = methodSearchSuccess && method != NULL

    MonoMethod* rtInitMethod;
    method_search("CitizenFX.Core.RuntimeManager:Initialize", rtInitMethod);
    method_search("CitizenFX.Core.RuntimeManager:GetImplementedClasses", g_getImplementsMethod);
    method_search("CitizenFX.Core.RuntimeManager:CreateObjectInstance", g_createObjectMethod);
    method_search("System.Diagnostics.EnhancedStackTrace:GetMethodDisplayString", g_getMethodDisplayStringMethod);

#if !defined(IS_FXSERVER) || defined(_WIN32)
    method_search("CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager:TickGlobal", g_tickMethod);
#endif

    if (!methodSearchSuccess)
    {
        FatalError("Couldn't find one or more CitizenFX.Core methods.\n");
    }

    MonoObject* exc = nullptr;
    mono_runtime_invoke(rtInitMethod, nullptr, nullptr, &exc);

    if (exc)
    {
        fx::mono::MonoComponentHostShared::PrintException(exc);
        return;
    }
}
```

I've tried fixing by asking for some people from the cfx.re community but it wasn't really helpful. I also checked on internet and the only thing that I found is the error guide from Microsoft for his error error ***CS0103***, but it was helpless. And the others that is getting this errors isn't really helpful for me. And yes I've followed all the process from [the little documentation](https://github.com/citizenfx/fivem/blob/master/docs/building.md).

Comment: *I am a beginner in C# and cpp* -- The error has nothing to do with C++.  The error is indicating that the issue is with C#.  Also, C++ and C# are two totally different languages -- you need to know which one is giving the issue so that your question uses the correct tags.

Comment: *I am a beginner in C# and cpp* Why cpp and not cs? Be consistent, distort both names.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's the C# file the problem, but I thought that giving another place where the EnhancedStackTrace is being used would have been a good idea!

Comment: @YOMAN1792 -- Please note that when you use tags, persons subscribed to the tag will have your question show up in their list of new questions.  Since the compilation error has nothing to do with C++, posting C++ code just to make the C++ tag "stick" is not a good idea.  That is akin to tag spamming.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok! So I should remove my cpp part code and the tags as well even if people have been already pinged?! Well I shouldn't remove my cpp code as it's seems to be used for the C# as well and vice versa I think

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting this error ? error CS0103: The name 'EnhancedStackTrace' does not exist in the current context

You are getting this error because the compiler/visual studio cannot locate a type named `EnhancedStackTrace` in your program code or within any referenced assembly (dll).

If I assume that the maintainer of that repo keeps it in a working state, then I would suggest going through the steps in the [Developer Guide](https://github.com/citizenfx/fivem/blob/master/docs/building.md) and make sure you execute each of them. If you skipped any, or if any of them had a problem when running, then that could mean that some necessary assembly was not downloaded/built/installed which would cause the error you are seeing.

Also, the `EnhancedStackTrace` in the C# code and the `EnhancedStackTrace` in the C++ code could be (and very likely are) two different type definitions that just share a name, like `integer` or `string`.